# Checking diagonals in a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find diagonals in a grid for the pattern `XOOX`. I have this function:

```
function chkDiagonal(token, x,y){
  if(x >= 0 && x - 2 >=0 && y >= 0){
     if(token === "X"){
         if(gameBoard[x][y]==="X" && gameBoard[x-1][y+1] === "O" 
           && gameBoard[x-2][y-2] === "O" && gameBoard[x-3][y+3]==="X"){
            return true;
           }
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

but it only returns `true` if I already have an `X` at `board[x-3][x+3]` I cannot figure out how to make it more general so that it only cares if there are already two `O's` in a row diagonally, and not in what order the `X's` are placed on either end. Could someone advise me on how to approach this?

I am testing it like this:

```
var gameBoard = [
       ["X", "O", "X", "O", "X", "O"],
       ["X", "O", "X", "X", "X", "O"],
       ["X", "O", "O", "O", "X", "O"],
       ["X", "O", "X", "O", "X", "O"],
       ["X", "O", "X", "O", "X", "O"]

      ];

console.log(chkDiagonal("X",4,0));//undefined
```

Comment: please add some data to check.

Comment: I added some testing data.

Comment: possible mistake here: `gameBoard[x-2][y-2] === "O"`, should be `y+2`

Comment: Add a `return false` at the end of method, so that it will return false if check fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to be pointed out.

- Firstly, in your condition you're checking for `gameBoard[x-2][y-2]` which should be `gameBoard[x-2][y+2]`
- Secondly, you should add a `return false` at the end of function, so that it will return false when check fails. If you don't add a return statement, it will return nothing and hence `undefined`.

Comment: `undefined` is falsey.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry. I did n't get you.

Comment: for simple checks, like `if (chkDiagonal(...)) { /* do something */ }` its working without explicit `false`.